# Pentaho PDI clone previous value

Tags: loops, etl, pentaho, pdi

]Hi Faced with a problem and do not yet know how to solve it correctly. I have a column with 3 values, and between them there are empty cells. I need to fill the cells between them with the previous value to the next new value. For example: from test 1 to test 2 all empty should be test2 from test 2 to test 3 should be test 3 and so on. Can you tell me how I can do this? Thanks

I have tried some js scripts but without any success, md in Pentaho there are some options to do it in loop

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with a javascript step. You will need two scripts there, one start script (runs when the transformation initialises) and one transform script (runs for each row).

The start script merely initialises a variable:

```
var a = null;
```

The transform script updates the value of that variable when the input field is not null. Otherwise it outputs the previous value:

```
if( club_code !== null ){
    a = club_code;  
}
```

Then you output field `a` as `club_code` setting the "Replace value" box as Y.

See pictures:

[image: Start script (right click to bring out menu)]

[image: Transform script]

Comment: First of all, thank you for the detailed response. I made a little mistake in the description, conditionally from test 1 to test 2 should be test 1 and so on, but so far it is not so fundamental. Unfortunately it did not work although I understood the principle of such a cycle with two scripts. To the description of the problem attached a screenshot that I did the same as you in your screenshots, but the result in the column club_code nothing has changed, the empty fields are not filled with the previous values. Can you correct please, I would be very grateful @nsousa

Comment: you may have missed a detail somewhere. It worked just fine on my computer. Also, it's not good form to edit a question after the answers come in, as then the answers provided make no sense given the question. The whole point of a SO question is to leave a document of the issue you had and the possible solutions offered, so others can then benefit from it in the future.